# can not assign value to a tableview cell controller variable

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm working on a project and I need to assign an id to every tableview cell so I can run the action on the right user
here is my code :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.results.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "searchcell") as! SearchTVC
    cell.username.text = self.filtered[indexPath.row].username as! String
    cell.id = self.filtered[indexPath.row].id as! String

    return cell
}
```

when I try to print the id I get an exception telling me that the id is nil

Comment: How are you creating id ? Add that code.

Comment: id  is label or else

Comment: id is a string variable @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: it's written this way : var id : String! @Priyal

Comment: @noone When you want this `id` of `Cell` ?

Comment: when u need u this `cell.id = self.filtered[indexPath.row].id as! String` else no need to use on `cellForRowAt`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I'm sorry I didn't understand you

Comment: @noone - no need of this `cell.id = self.filtered[indexPath.row].id as! String` in tablview, if you want to access some you can directly get the id

Comment: @noone are you able to print the value for `self.filtered[indexPath.row].id as! String` ?

Comment: ...say, `let iii = self.filtered[indexPath.row].id` - i understand `iii` is non-nil. So  if you get nil at some place where you call `cell.id` - you may want to share that part as well. Possibly, you are not retaining the string; or the cell object itself is nil.

Comment: in addition, storing data in the cell like that is a bad idea, generally speaking. In a scenario where the user taps a cell, you will have the cell's indexPath - you should use it to retrieve the `let id = self.filtered[indexPath.row]!`, instead of assigning it to the cell (a view). You can think of a `id` as data, which belongs in a model layer - try not to mix things into views.

Comment: where to use cell.id?

Comment: Thank you guys I changed the way the API works and used the cell labels as entries and everything went great !